# How I should use ajax to fire a web service call to export an Excel

Tags: java, ajax, excel, blob

updated question:
On server side i have a service as below, if I want to use ajax to fire the call on the client side, how I should do that?

In server:
Java/Spring

```
@GET
@Produces("application/vnd.ms-excel")
@Path("permissions/all/{userList}")
public Response allPermissionsExcel(@PathParam("userList") String userList) throws IOException {    
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
HSSFWorkbook wb;
try {
        String[] groupList = userList.split(",");
        wb = this.excelPermissionsService.getPermissionsExcelWorkbook(groupList);
        wb.write(baos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        baos.close();
    }
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok(bytes);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=export.xls");
    return response.build();
}
```

In client:

```
$scope.exportToExcel = function() {
  var promise = usersResource.getExcelPermissions($scope.userList);
  promise.$promise.then(function(data) {
//I tried to convert to blob then save it with FileSaver.js, but I got an issue in converting the object to blob.
  var blob = new Blob([data],
            var blob = new Blob([data],
            {type: "application/octet-stream"});
  saveAs(blob, "exportThis.xls");
  });
};
```

in the client side, if i use ajax (above code) to fire a call to server, and it returns an object, but nothing prompts up to download, unless I use

```
window.location = "url here";
```

to fire the call. But that's a redirect and pops up to download after all javascript ran.

Since I have some loading animations which are applied by $watch, i need to use ajax to fire the call instead of using window.location.

Can anyone help me save the "data" object excel in client side?
Thanks!

Comment: I'm curious now that I see what you're doing... have your tried doing this but with and xlsx file. I'm currently working on something similar but with an xlsx file and it is not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use window.open without requesting an ajax 
it will just open a new window and then the file will start download without affecting the current page

```
window.open("permissions/all/1"); // instead of window.location because it will move you to another page
```

You also can open it by a pop up like this

```
newwindow=window.open("permissions/all/1","Window name",'height=50,width=150); // this one is better because it will open a small window without hiding the current window 
       if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
       return false;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It works , but the loading animation which is applied by angular $watch is not showing. Is there a way to handle the return 'data' in promise and save to excel for download?

Comment: Happy to hear that it helped you, accept this answer to help other people who are facing same problem, unfortunately i never used Angular before. but you can't retrieve two types of responses at the same time, so if it is jsoin it will be retrieved json if it is a application/vnd.ms-excel it will retrieve  only excel , in case you really really need both of them (download, read content) you need to do 2 requests one for pulling normal data and the second one for creating excel and in this case the above solution will not work

Comment: i think it returns application/vnd.ms-excel as byte array. Since $promise was used, it expects a return, thus does not pop anything on the bottom browser. I guess my question should be how i can use ajax to fire the call.

Comment: Since your api is get it will start download immeditly